# how to collapse div on media query for mobile only (without javascript / only bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Regarding Bootstrap 4:
i was trying to collapse .card div on mobile view only.
i tried .collapse class but in this way it collapses on all sizes of screen. here are my codes in case if somebody wants to see;

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="card>
        <div class="card-header">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#t10"><h3>Top 10</h3></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body collapse" id="t10">
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-12>
                <h4>ABC</h4>
                <h5>Review: <img src="../../images/4stars.png"><br></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

after spending hours searching on internet, i didn't find anything probably i was using wrong search terms (as newbie), I got an idea to reverse the situation so I un-collapsed for =>992px in media query, codes as following:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #t10.collapse { display: block; }
}
```

As you can see it is OK but I really want to learn the best way to collapse a div/card when screen size changes to less than 992px.

(Pardon my English. I am not Eng speaker).

Comment: You have totally broken HTML code in there. I recommend you start by fixing that first. Use a proper code editor that automatically highlights invalid code. Brackets: http://brackets.io is a very good editor for beginners.

Comment: i am using Sublime Text. I'll try to render codes. Thx for the suggestion.

Comment: Then turn on the options in Sublime that automatically highlight invalid code. In a good editor, you don't need to "render" anything. A good code editor will immediately highlight invalid code while you are typing it.

Comment: I've downloaded Brackets. For instance, I have edited posted to improve codes.

Comment: That code is still totally broken. Create a new HTML file i.e. file that ends with `.html` and paste in your that code snippet from above. What do you see? Do you see that the code is totally broken and highlighted in red?

Answer (score 3):

Just add *.dont-collapse-sm* class to Your collapsible div to not disappear over 768px breakpoint.

Credits for: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/xryaKK (also helped me a lot!)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .collapse.dont-collapse-sm {
    display: block;
    height: auto !important;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [responsive display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/).

For example,

`<div class="card-body d-none d-lg-flex" id="t10"></div>`

Will hide this DIV on screen widths less that 992px.

Comment: thanks for reply but I want to make it collapse like nav collapses and show hamburger icon. small device users will tap to show its content.

Comment: That's a different question. It has nothing to do with the cards you've shown. Read the docs on the nav or update the question.

Comment: I read the docs display utilities which provides hiding utility which is another good information for me. Ok, after this comment, I'm going to read nav docs to see if able to collapse card or any div other than nav.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 providing classes for responsive screen. like col-lg-* col-sm-*

So, You can try changing the display by using the bootstrap class itself.

E.g.

```
<div class="d-block d-sm-block d-md-flex d-lg-flex d-xl-flex">
  /** your content **/
</div>
```

This classes will change the display property for every screens which we mentioned.

For your reference, Check the Bootstrap 4 Docs: [Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Comment: thanks for reply but I want to make it collapse like nav collapses and show hamburger icon. small device users will tap to show its content.

Comment: Can you provide Snippet JSfiddle? Bootstrap 4 will automatically provide the collapses function. Refer this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#toggler